# Sphinx docstring formatting for generic class

Tags: python, generics, python-sphinx, python-typing, docstring

I got a method with the return type `Collection[Championship]` where `Collection` is a generic class (inherits `typing.Generic[T]`) and `Championship` is just a default class.

Now I don't know how to reference the classes in the docstring with Sphinx. I already tried these things:

```
:rtype: :class:`.Collection`[:class:`.Championship`]
:rtype: :class:`.Collection[.Championship]`
```

But none of them seems to work. (The last one looks good in html, but there is no ref if you click on it)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but could be considered: If you use Python 3 type hinting, Sphinx can automatically pick up these hints and you do not need to write rtype yourself. Some example Sphinx documentation doing this here: https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/api/client/help/tradingstrategy.client.Client.html#tradingstrategy.client.Client